# Trying to pass a function as a parameter using functional library in c++ but it is not working

Tags: c++, function, vector

// I will define all the functions that are involved.

//First is the sort function that i am trying to pass.

```
void bubbleSort(vector<int> &vector);
```

//Second is the function that calls the function that is supposed to take a function as a parameter.

```
int testSorts(vector<int> &vector, ofstream& outfile, string data)
{
    displaySort(vector, outfile, sortName, bubbleSort);
}
```

//This is the function that is supposed to take a vector, file, and function as parameter.

// When I run this I get the following error. [Error] template argument 1 is invalid

```
void displaySort(vector<int>& vector, ofstream& outfile, string data, std::function<void 
(vector<int>& vector)> func)
{func(vector);}
```

//Here is the code I got from stack overflow that works. What I want to know is why mine does not. I did the same thing.

```
#include <functional>

double Combiner(double a, double b, std::function<double 
(double,double)> func){
  return func(a,b);
}

double Add(double a, double b){
  return a+b;
}

double Mult(double a, double b){
  return a*b;
}

int main(){
  Combiner(12,13,Add);
  Combiner(12,13,Mult);
}
```

Comment: I would like to mention that yes I have been looking through stack overflow for the answer to this problem and that is where I found about the functional library. Also, I have not put all of the details of the functions in there, only that matter.

Comment: Above is the program of some guy on stack overflow, it works but mine doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: Please do not post code and question updates in comments, [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `using namespace std;` and specify the namespace and it should work:

```
void displaySort(std::vector<int>& vector, std::ofstream& outfile,
                 std::string data, std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> func) 
{
    func(vector);
}
```

If you for some reason want to stick with `using namespace std;`, add `::` before `vector` in the `function` spec:

```
void displaySort(vector<int>& vector, ofstream& outfile,
                 string data, function<void(::vector<int>&)> func)
//                                          ^^
{
    func(vector);
}
```